# Having issues importing seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

For some reason I can't import seaborn. I'm trying to use it in Jupyter. I have Python 3.6.5 installed. I used pip to install seaborn. I looked at similar questions regarding this, but I'm kinda new to python and it's hard to

Input:

```
#import necessaries libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

I get this error:

```
   ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-eaef722397b2> in <module>()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 5 import seaborn as sns

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 
      5 # Import seaborn objects
----> 6 from .rcmod import *
      7 from .utils import *
      8 from .palettes import *

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py in <module>()
      3 import functools
      4 import matplotlib as mpl
----> 5 from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
      6 
      7 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/palettes.py in <module>()
     10 from .external.six.moves import range
     11 
---> 12 from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
     13 from .colors import xkcd_rgb, crayons
     14 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/utils.py in <module>()
      5 
      6 import numpy as np
----> 7 from scipy import stats
      8 import pandas as pd
      9 import matplotlib as mpl

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py in <module>()
    346 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    347 
--> 348 from .stats import *
    349 from .distributions import *
    350 from .morestats import *

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in <module>()
    173 from scipy._lib.six import callable, string_types
    174 from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion
--> 175 import scipy.special as special
    176 import scipy.linalg as linalg
    177 from . import distributions

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py in <module>()
    638 from .sf_error import SpecialFunctionWarning, SpecialFunctionError
    639 
--> 640 from ._ufuncs import *
    641 
    642 from .basic import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.special._ufuncs'
```

Any ideas on what I need to do? I tried reinstalling but it didnt work.

Comment: try reinstalling scipy and then seaborn

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and show the intermediate traceback?

Comment: check dependent packages,
Mandatory dependencies
numpy (>= 1.9.3)
scipy (>= 0.14.0)
matplotlib (>= 1.4.3)
pandas (>= 0.15.2)
Recommended dependencies
statsmodels (>= 0.5.0)

Comment: please provide details about install version on your system for following modules.
scipy
numpy
matplotlib
statsmodels
it seems like you are missing statsmodules